# How to read Json File into a list of Rows?

Tags: python, json

I am trying to read a JSON file into lists of Rows where each entry in the list is a single row from the file.

See code below

with open("C:\Users\Derrick.Speirs\Desktop\jcpenney_reviewers.json", "r") as fid:
dat = [dict(json.loads(row)) for row in fid]
print(dat)
display(type(dat))

This code results in the following whereby each entry is not on a single row.

[{'ID': 'bkpn1412', 'DOB': '31.07.1988', 'State': 'Oregon', 'Reviewed': ['cea76118f6a9110a893de2b7654319c0']}, {'Usern

Any help appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("C:\\Users\\David.Johnson\\Desktop\\bigjohn.json", "r") as fid:
    dat = [dict(json.loads(line)) for line in fid]
```

Using dict and zip might cause the issue

Comment: Thanks. That sorrted it. Appreciated

Comment: I am glad I was able to help

Comment: The only issue now is each entry is not on a single row.